# Packagist - add more than one repositories

Tags: github, packagist

I added my first repository to Packagist yesterday. Today, I wanted to add a second package from the same vendor. But Packagist refused to take it. It gives me the following message:

```
The vendor is already taken by someone else. You may ask them to add 
your package and give you maintainership access. The packages 
already in that vendor namespace can be found at 
<a href="/packages/fabian/">fabian</a>
```

It is strange, because my vendor-name is `brotzka` and not fabian. The package name is `laravel-dotenv-editor`. So the complete repository could be found under `https://github.com/Brotzka/laravel-dotenv-editor`.

My previous Package was also submitted under the vendor brotzka.

My Packagist-Username is Brotzka.

How can I add my second package? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. In my composer.json, I had an error in the "name"-tag. There the package was named `fabian/laravel-dotenv-editor`.

Changed it to `brotzka/laravel-dotenv-editor` and everything was fine.

Comment: 4 years later, this helped me :-)